# How to get a password encrypted since the Java Script file in my web application?

Tags: javascript, web-services, encryption

I'm designing some code for a standard login in a web application, I consider that doing the **password encryption** on **client side** is better than making mongo server doing it.

So, if I have this code ...

```
$("#btnSignUp").click( function () {

        var sign = {

            user:$("#signUser").val(),
            pass:$("#signPass").val()
        };

    });
```

And then I'd do a **post** of `sign` with the password value already encrypted, how could I achieve this? Does JavaScript support AES?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should submit the login page over https and make use of certificates to do the encryption. JavaScript is never a good idea for things that need security since you can control/influence the execution of it using developer tools built into most browsers

Answer (score 1):

There are many libraries available for javascript to encrypt your data. Check out http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using AES encryption in your JavaScript code. See Javascript AES encryption for libraries and links. The trouble you'll have is picking a key that is only available on the client side. Perhaps you can prompt the user? Or hash together some client system information that's not sent to the server.

kindly refer this link

http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/

```
AES_Init();

var block = new Array(16);
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  block[i] = 0x11 * i;

var key = new Array(32);
for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++)
  key[i] = i;

AES_ExpandKey(key);
AES_Encrypt(block, key);

AES_Done();
```

Comment: Well, following to the other answers ... As long as this is a login app for a social network, I think https would solve it. What do you think?

Comment: hmmm , yup.  Http will help you out